# Having an issue with dropdown showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, navigation, gradient

I'm not sure why this downdown menu won't show up in IE. Can anyone see what the problem is? It works in all the other browsers, just not IE. I know gradients in IE take a lot of thought. Here is my code.

```
.menu { 
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background: #006699; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #006699 0%, #1f416b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#006699), color-stop(100%,#1f416b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #006699 0%,#1f416b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #006699 0%,#1f416b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #006699 0%,#1f416b 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #006699 0%,#1f416b 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#1f416b'); /* IE6-9 */  
}

.menu li a {
   padding: 15px 45px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;      
}

.menu li.current > a,
.menu li.current > a:hover,
.menu li.current.hover > a {
   background: rgb(70,168,217); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%, rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%, rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(122,188,255,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(96,171,248,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(64,150,238,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7abcff', endColorstr='#4096ee',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(122,188,255,1) 0%,rgba(96,171,248,1) 44%,rgba(64,150,238,1) 100%); /* W3C */
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   cursor: default;
}

.menu li a:hover,
.menu li.hover > a {
   background: #b32416; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b32416 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b32416), color-stop(44%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#6d0019)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b32416 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b32416 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b32416 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b32416 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b32416', endColorstr='#6d0019'); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: I use this site to create all my gradients. Always works. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Can we get an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @VukašinManojlović yea I will upload an example in FS fiddle and provide a link.

Comment: @fredsbend I will try that and see if it will work. I will use this for feature reference also!

Answer (score 0):

Which IE version?

I know that you need something like this in the head of your html page. Has to do with SVG or something. Conditional Formatting.

```
<!-- following class is conditional for IE9 and must be put in elements for css gradient to work -->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Then apply this gradient class to elements using the gradients.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**EDIT**

OK. Did a little research and found that the filter should have an 8 digit hex code where the first two are the opacity. I think FF for 100% and 00 for 0%. Also, use double quotes ". Might make a difference.

So do something like this:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
(startColorstr="#ff7abcff",endColorstr="#ff4096ee",GradientType=0);
```

Comment: The version of IE that it is not working for is IE8. Here is a link to the page that I am referring to (http://www.condley.com/condley-llp). The Nav works in all other browsers just not in IE8.

Comment: I tried that edit and I still didn't get any anything when I hovered over the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Ajay Are you sure it is the gradient causing issues? Remove all gradients and see if the dropdown then shows on IE8. All the stuff under "Menu Styles" in default960. Change to simple one color hex. If it does show then it is the gradients causing issues, if not then it is not the gradients. I think IE8 had developer tools; you can remove styles one at a time without editing the page. F12 when on the page.

Comment: you were right. Once I checked the developer tools in IE8 and started disabling styles. The dropdown menu still did not work. So I'm guessing it is the JS.